# How do I calculate values for the current user in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application with a series of tests (FirstTest, SecondTest etc.)

Each test has a calculation set out its relevant model that gets calculated before being saved to the database set out like this:

```
#first_test.rb
before_save :calculate_total

private 

def calculate_total
...
end
```

I then have an index page for each user (welcome/index) which displays the current user's results for each test. This all works fine, however I want to work out various other things such as each users average score overall etc.

Is it possible to access the current user from the welcome model?

Currently my welcome.rb is accessing the data follows:

```
#welcome.rb
def self.total

   FirstTest.last.total

end
```

This obviously access the last overall test NOT the last test from the current user.

I feel like I may have just laid the whole application out in a fairly unintelligent manner...

Thanks in advance x

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to save user_id in a column for each record in FirstTest. Then you can find the total for current user

```
FirstTest.where(:user_id => current_user.id).last.total
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already have a user_id column. However if I use that code it still can't locate the current_user it comes up with: 

    "undefined local variable or method `current_user' for Welcome(id: 
    integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime):Class Did you 
    mean? current_scope"

Comment: Ok you need to get the current user somehow. How are you authenticating the user? You can use devise if you want to https://github.com/plataformatec/devise